# render in rails with collection is printing thrice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, renderpartial, mongoid3

I am using Mongodb with ROR . This is the command:

```
<%= render partial: "show", collection: @h %>
```

Where `@h` is

```
@h=[
  {"folder"=>"Default", "weight"=>"100.0", "stocks"=>[
    {"id"=>"id1", "name"=>"Ajanta Pharma Ltd.", "weight"=>"57.0"},
    {"id"=>"id11", "name"=>"Avanti Feeds Ltd.", "weight"=>"5.1"}, 
    {"id"=>"id34", "name"=>"MPS Ltd.", "weight"=>"2.5"}, 
    {"id"=>"id89", "name"=>"Poly Medicure Ltd.", "weight"=>"3.7"}]}, 
  {"folder"=>"low margin", "weight"=>"0.0", "stocks"=>[
    ]}, 
  {"folder"=>"fjf", "weight"=>"0.0", "stocks"=>[
  ]}
]
```

Suppose my `_show.erb` is this

```
i am line
```

The output i am getting is `i am linei am linei am line` actually no. of times the folder in `@h` * content in `_show.erb` If I change `@h` to this

```
@h=[
  {"folder"=>"Default", "weight"=>"100.0", "stocks"=>[
    {"id"=>"id1", "name"=>"Ajanta Pharma Ltd.", "weight"=>"57.0"},
    {"id"=>"id11", "name"=>"Avanti Feeds Ltd.", "weight"=>"5.1"}, 
    {"id"=>"id34", "name"=>"MPS Ltd.", "weight"=>"2.5"}, 
    {"id"=>"id89", "name"=>"Poly Medicure Ltd.", "weight"=>"3.7"}]}, 
  {"folder"=>"low margin", "weight"=>"0.0", "stocks"=>[
    ]}` 
]
```

Then it gives `i am linei am line` as folder are 2 why it is happening as only want one time output irrespective of no. of folders . How can I do that?

Comment: are the tick marks around the array in `@h` there in your code or just in the post?

Comment: Just in the post let me edit it. Now its okey.

Answer (score 0):

Done , actually When you pass a collection to a partial via the :collection option, the partial will be inserted once for each member in the collection:

so I used this: <%= render partial: "show", object: @h %>